# Need Help on Translating C# to F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#

I need help on translating custom extension for IndexOfAny for string as existing framework does not have IndexOfAny that matching string values. Already translated my own. However I have no idea how to break out of loop by return value. Any idea how to break out of loop or better solution.
Below is my translation.

**C#**

```
public static int IndexOfAnyCSharp(this string str, string[] anyOff) {
    if (str != null && anyOff != null)
        foreach (string value in anyOff) {
            int index = str.IndexOf(value);
            if (index > -1) return index;
        }
    return -1;
}
```

**F#**

```
[<Extension>]
static member public IndexOfAnyFSharp(str:string, anyOff:string[]) =
    match str <> null && anyOff <> null with
    | true ->
        let mutable index = -1
        for value in anyOff do
            if index = -1 then
                index <- str.IndexOf(value)
        index
    | false -> -1
```

Comment: You cannot break out of for loops in F#. There is some discussion around this [here](https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/381).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Seq.tryFind` is your friend. A basic building block would be something like

```
let IndexOfAny (s: string, manyStrings: string seq) = 
    manyStrings
    |> Seq.map (fun m -> s.IndexOf m)
    |> Seq.tryFind (fun index -> index >= 0)
```

This will return `None` if nothing matches - this is more idiomatic F# than returning -1: The compiler will force you to think about the case that nothing matches.

Update: You may prefer:

```
let IndexOfAny (s: string, manyStrings: string seq) = 
    manyStrings
    |> Seq.tryPick (fun m ->
        match s.IndexOf m with
        | -1 -> None
        | i -> Some i
    )
```

Comment: another option - to use `Array.tryPick`

Comment: True, but I think you will always end up with more lines of code than with this 2-stage approach...

Comment: Not necessarily: `|> Seq.tryPick (fun m -> match m.IndexOf m with -1 -> None | i -> Some i)`

Comment: Yeah, OK, in the end it's a matter of taste. I personally would not put that into a single line.

Comment: Hi Anton! Thanks for your advice. Actually I do know that in F# returning -1 is not idiomatic. But actually I'm changing bit by bit of existing C# code to F# and projects with interface are still using C# for front-end. So will ended up returning FSharpOption. Well I do understood from your code to convert 'None' into -1 already.

Comment: @crystalcoder - well, if you are just changing C# to F# with a one-to-one mapping of method signatures, then I personally don't think there's much to be gained from the exercise. You will not be able to benefit much from the awesome features that F# gives you in terms of safeguarding your code against overlooked corner cases, avoiding null references, immutability, etc. I'd first re-write the core such that it makes best use of F#, and then add C#-friendly interfaces, see [sec. 6 of the design guidelines](http://fsharp.org/specs/component-design-guidelines/)

Comment: @Anton - Actually I do thought of that. But since I'm actually direct working on actual client's project at the same time for learning purpose, I needed fast development which I had known for time being. So, anything that I didn't knew how on F#, i coded it on C# first to save time. Also re-using some old created libraries. One of the reason I decided to use F# was also because of avoiding null errors. But seems it can't help if null was passed in from C# code.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Seq.tryFind` or `Array.tryFind` is idiomatic F# but also has different performance characteristics than the C# loop. Especially `Seq` module is problematic when it comes to performance and memory overhead. This can sometimes be of importance.

As others noted in F# you can't exit early from a for loop. I used to be bothered about that but no longer am as F# supports tail call elimination that allow us to implement the loop as a tail recursive function.

Below is an example on how to use tail recursion. The code below should perform roughly similar to the C# loop. I don't exactly implement the semantics of the C# in that I return an `Result<int*int, Unit>` instead. I use `Result` over `option` because `Result` doesn't add GC pressure as it's a struct type.

Also included is a neat way IMO to protect F# code from the dangers of null values.

```
// If our function is callable from C# we can use active patterns as a neat way to protect our
//  F# code from null values
//  Functions that are only callable from F# code we don't need to protect as long as we protect
//  the entry points
let inline (|DefaultTo|) dv v = if System.Object.ReferenceEquals (v, null) then dv else v
let inline (|NotNull|) v      = if System.Object.ReferenceEquals (v, null) then raise (System.NullReferenceException ()) else v

let emptySet : string [] = [||]

let indexOfSet (DefaultTo "" str) (DefaultTo emptySet set) : Result<int*int, unit> =
    // In F# tail recursion is used as a more powerful looping construct
    //  F# suppports tail call elimination meaning under the hood this is
    //  implemented as an efficient loop
    //  Note: I pass str and set as argument in order to make F# doesn't
    //  create new lambda object that closes over them (reduces GC load)
    let rec loop (str : string) (set : string []) i =
        if i < set.Length then
            let index = str.IndexOf set.[i]
            if index = -1 then loop str set (i + 1)
            else Ok (i, index)
        else
          Error ()
    loop str set 0

printfn "%A" <| indexOfSet null null
printfn "%A" <| indexOfSet null     [| "abc"; "ab"; "a" |]
printfn "%A" <| indexOfSet ""       [| "abc"; "ab"; "a" |]
printfn "%A" <| indexOfSet "a"      [| "abc"; "ab"; "a" |]
printfn "%A" <| indexOfSet "ab"     [| "abc"; "ab"; "a" |]
printfn "%A" <| indexOfSet "abc"    [| "abc"; "ab"; "a" |]
printfn "%A" <| indexOfSet "da"     [| "abc"; "ab"; "a" |]
printfn "%A" <| indexOfSet "dab"    [| "abc"; "ab"; "a" |]
printfn "%A" <| indexOfSet "dabc"   [| "abc"; "ab"; "a" |]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Will try it up some time as what you mentioned may be right since I'm not familiar with F# yet. In my own current actual function, I did use 'match' to match whether both string and array passed and direct returns -1 if any is null. So for null handling was solved anyway.

Comment: Either way, I'll still have to convert your code into 'type' and 'member' where in C# can be detected as static extension method. in a way I can use it as `"hello world goodbye".IndexOfAny("world","yahoo")`

Comment: I realise this, the post was more to demonstrate exiting "loops" using tail-recursion.